# Cascading Dropdown in Handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable, cascadingdropdown

I am trying to make a dropdown type column while the conditions are determined by another cell's content.

The columns settings are built by a function, where when it should be a cascading dropdown, the source is a function as well.

Everything is working fine, and the function is been called when you double click on the cell. The function is running and return the right array. But the dropdown doesn't open.

Short version of the JS:

```
data: Object.keys(data[0])[i],
type: "dropdown",
source: function getDropdownList() {
          // function build the array
          return dropdownOptions;
        }
```

Long version of the JS:

```
var myData = Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(5, 5);
var container = document.getElementById('table1');
var settings1 = {
   data: myData,
   columns: buildTypeObject()
}

var table1 = new Handsontable(container, settings1);

function buildTypeObject() {
  var typeObject = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    if (i=1) {
        typeObject[i] = {
            data: ("column " + i),
            type: "dropdown",
            source: function getDropdownList() {
                var dropdownOptions = [];
                var selectedRow = table1.getSelected()[0];
                var selectedColumn = table1.getSelected()[1];
                var previousCell = table1.getDataAtCell(selectedRow, selectedColumn-1);
                if (previousCell == "A1") {
                    dropdownOptions = ["AB1","BB1"];
                } else {
                    dropdownOptions = ["ZZ1", "ZZ2", "ZZ3", "ZZ4"];                        
                }
                console.log(dropdownOptions);
                return dropdownOptions;            
            }
        }                
    } else {
        typeObject[i] = {
            data: ("column " + i) 
        }            
    }
 };
 return typeObject;
};
```

Comment: can you put a console log statement right before the return? when you say that clicking doesn't open the dropdown, is dropdownOptions empty or undefined?

Comment: also try accessing this new object and check what the `source` field says. Again, is it empty or undefined?

Comment: Yes, I put a console log to check if the input is correct, and it is. What do you mean by the "source" field?

Comment: You can even see the console log in the above code

Comment: My bad, yeah then check the source field. I meant call your instance and check the `columns` object then check that the `source` option is set correctly.

Comment: While following your suggestion I found a method that fixes my problem - setCellMeta(row, col, key, value). I will upload the fix as an answer, although it's not 100% fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix this with the `setCellMeta(row, col, key, value)` method.

So now the JS looks like this:

```
var myData = Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(5, 5);
var container = document.getElementById('table1');
var settings1 = {
   data: myData,
   columns: buildTypeObject()
}

var table1 = new Handsontable(container, settings1);

function buildTypeObject() {
  var typeObject = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    if (i=1) {
        typeObject[i] = {
            data: ("column " + i),
            type: "dropdown",
            source: function getDropdownList() {
                var dropdownOptions = [];
                var selectedRow = table1.getSelected()[0];
                var selectedColumn = table1.getSelected()[1];
                var previousCell = table1.getDataAtCell(selectedRow, selectedColumn-1);
                if (previousCell == "A1") {
                    dropdownOptions = ["AB1","BB1"];
                } else {
                    dropdownOptions = ["ZZ1", "ZZ2", "ZZ3", "ZZ4"];                        
                }
                console.log(dropdownOptions);
                //return dropdownOptions;
                setCellMeta(selectedRow, selectedCol, "source", dropdownOptions);            
            }
        }                
    } else {
        typeObject[i] = {
            data: ("column " + i) 
        }            
    }
```

The only problem is that the dropdown list doesn't open on the first click, it does on the second click though or when I edit the cell (type in any character or erase)

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code will help someone based on my findings.

select2-editor exposing callback onBeginEditing

```
$("#hot").handsontable({           
        onBeginEditing: function () {
            var activeEditor = instance.getActiveEditor();
            var selectedRow = activeEditor.cellProperties.row
            var selectedColumn = activeEditor.cellProperties.col;
            if ( selectedColumn == 3) {
                var tester = instance.getDataAtCell(selectedRow, 14);
                var filterlist = [];
                var optionsList = activeEditor.options.data;
                for (var index = 0; index < optionsList.length; index++) {
                    if (tester == optionsList[index].tester) {
                        filterlist.push(optionsList[index]);
                    }
                }
                activeEditor.options.data = filterlist;
            }
        });
```